# How to add image in column of React Virtualized library table

Tags: reactjs

How to insert images in column of React virtualised library table,
i have tried adding in dataKey property of column, but it is not loading, what can be the solution

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Column, Table, AutoSizer, Grid } from 'react-virtualized';

class TableComponent extends Component{
 state={
  callLogsColumnsData: null
 }
 componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({callLogsColumnsData: this.props.tableData});
 }
 render(){
  return(
   <Table
    sortBy="rank"
    sortDirection="DESC"
    width={width}
    height={820}
    headerHeight={20}
    rowHeight={60}
    headerClassName='call-logs-table-header'
    rowClassName='call-logs-row-table'
    style={{borderBottom: "solid 1px #000"}}
    onRowClick={this.onRowClick}
    rowCount={this.state.callLogsColumnsData.length}
    rowGetter={({ index }) => this.state.callLogsColumnsData[index]}
   >
    <Column
     label='CALL ID'
     dataKey='callId'
     width={100}
     className="table-column"
    />
   </Table>
  )
 }
}
export default TableComponent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
< Column
width = {
  130
}
label = 'CLI LOCATION'
dataKey = 'cliLocation'
cellData = ''
cellRenderer = {
  this.cliLocationColumnData
}
/>

cliLocationColumnData = ({
  cellData,
  dataKey
}) => {
  return ( <
    div >
    <
    img src = {
      GB_FLAG
    }
    alt = 'imageName' / >
    <
    span > {
      dataKey
    } < /span> <
    /div>
  )
}
```